# Corba naming service

Tags: corba

i need some help here...

I have to communicate ma Corba server with one Java web service...
so i have to cinfigure the naming service.. right??

I kill the omniNames in port 2809 and run the code:
tnameserv -ORBport 2809

and gives me

Initial Naming Context:
IOR:000000000000002b49444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e300000000000010000000000000096000102000000000a3132372e302e312e3100038400000045afabcb0000000020000f424000000001000000000000000200000008526f6f74504f41000000000d544e616d65536572766963650000000000000008000000010000000114000000000000020000000100000020000000000001000100000002050100010001002000010109000000010001010000000026000000020002
TransientNameServer: setting port for initial object references to: 900
Ready.

and after i ran the server.py and returns the exception:

File "server.py", line 28, in 
    obj = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omniORB/CORBA.py", line 576, in resolve_initial_references
    return _omnipy.orb_func.resolve_initial_references(self, identifier)
omniORB.CORBA.NO_RESOURCES: CORBA.NO_RESOURCES(omniORB.NO_RESOURCES_InitialRefNotFound, CORBA.COMPLETED_NO)

what i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert for the Java name service but the default orb of the Corba spec is 2809.
While the java default is 900. Your nameservice starts at 900 like it told you but omniorb will look for it at 2809.

Web says the syntax for tnameserv is:

```
tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 2809
```

Answer (score 0):

First run this command on your terminal. (Make sure you have installed the JDK):

```
orbd -ORBInitialiPort 2809.
```

After that you have to run the server then run the client.